# How to fix dc 12 led lights that burn out due to excess voltage or current

Tags: led, dc, solar-charge-controller, lm78xx

How to limit the output DC voltage to dc 12V if the input voltage is greater than DC 12v,  and it outputs same voltage if voltage is below 12 V like 11.5 V or 10.5 V?

Scenario:

I have solar setup at home in which pwm 12 V solar charge controller is installed and 180 amp tall tubular battery is installed. I am running this setup to power my 12 V led lights and 12 V DC fans.

Problem is during the day time when sun is present my led lights burns out and that is probably due to excess voltage if i'm not wrong. Sometimes led lights flicker and they burn out.

So I am thinking to add 7812 IC to limit output voltage at 12 V, but I am afraid if my battery is drained out and it provide less than dc 12V, will this 7812 IC work properly?

Or, what should I add to limit the output voltage to DC 12 V if the input voltage is greater than that and it outputs same voltage if voltage is below 12 V?

Edit:
Dc fan probably consumes 3 to 4amps
and dc lights vary from 1amp to 2amp

Comment: I think a 12V zener diode would do the trick, depending on the power you need. Have you considered this? Is the leak of a diode too high for your case?

Comment: for efficiency i would use a buck controller instead of linear regulator .. what is power needed on 12v anyway ... probably cheap chineese buck 2A is enough ?

Comment: Have you actually measured this? A voltmeter would make a useful permanent addition to the setup.

Comment: @Juan um, that sounds like a terrible idea, considering that a DC fan probably uses more than a couple milliampere.

Comment: A 7812 is not going to work, a 7812 needs 15 V or more to be able to output a constant 12 V. You do not seem to have 15 V or more available so a 7812 doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Buck-boost regulator.

Comment: @MarcusMüller indeed, he edited the power in later, zener diode is a no go with that current

Comment: Ah, Juan, I see.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you do not tell us how much **current** is needed by your LEDs and fans.

Assuming that this current is less than 2 A you could consider using a **buck-boost** converter [like this](https://store.createlabz.com/product/81-013/):

[image]

In the description this model is listed as usable up to 3 A but you have to take that with a grain of salt. I'd use it up to 1 A and not be worried. Maybe it would survive 2 A just fine, At 3 A it might get **too hot** and not work in the long run. Then it would be better to use a module rated for 5 A.

Actually the name is wrong as the converter first **boosts** the voltage up to for example 24 V and then uses a DCDC down converter (a buck converter) to lower the voltage to the voltage you need, for example 12 V.

This means the module will output 12 V as long as the input voltage stays within (quite broad) limits. So even at 10.5 V or 15 V at the input, you will always get 12 V at the output.

There are many different modules similar to this one, just search for "Buck boost module".

Answer (score 0):

This is an XY problem.  This is a warning sign of something *seriously wrong with  your system*.  Don't apply technology to *hide the symptom*.  That's like making a mechanical [canary for use in a coal mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_species), since the regular canaries keep dying for ??? reason.

### You have worse problems. Your battery is getting destroyed.

The fact of your LEDs burning out is a **huge red flag** indicating that your solar system has a problem that is wrecking stuff.

It's clear your solar charge controller is either a) miswired, or b) defective.  It is not regulating the voltage from the solar panel, which typically ranges in the 15-19 volt range (or higher if it's a "24V" panel).

LED strips and other LED light products are designed to be tolerant of voltages ranging from 11V to 14.5V.  That is because they are designed to work in vehicles and other places with a 12V battery *being charged*.  The charging float voltage of a 12V lead-acid battery is 13.8 volts DC.

LED strips are a resistor in series with highly non-linear LEDs.  So if voltage increases, current increases roughly in proportion. Burning up LED strips suggests voltage is over 15V and probably closer to the 19V typical "open circuit" voltage of a solar panel.  That plainly indicates a defective or miswired charge controller.

This overvoltage is also boiling the water out of your battery, and shortening its life.

Either shoot us some pix of the charge controller's wiring and ask us to review, or if 100% confident in the wiring, it's time to get a voltmeter and actually measure these voltages.

Charge controllers are often cheap junk.  Try MorningStar; they are an excellent brand with some modest sized charge controllers.